# Creating directory for OkHttp cache on Android?

Tags: android, caching, okhttp

On Android, how should I create the `File` parameter for the `com.squareup.okhttp.Cache` constructor? It seems like `Context` gives you plenty of options:

- `new File(context.getCacheDir(), "HttpResponseCache")`
- `new File(context.getExternalCacheDir(), "HttpResponseCache")`
- `context.getDir("HttpResponseCache", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`

Just wondering what best practice is. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first one should work nicely, and gives your user a mechanism to free up disk space is necessary.